# ¿Cambiar el tipo de mapa dinámiamente desde FloatingButton en Kotlin?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, floating-action-button

Estoy intentando cambiar dinamicamente el tipo de mapa de mi aplicación por medio de un FloatingButton al presionarlo.

El problema es que sólo he encontrado ejemplos en Java para poderlo cambiar desde el `MainActivity.kt`

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
fun ChangeType(view: View) { //Función que vincula al FloatingRadioButton del XML
if(mMap.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL){
            mMap.setMapStyle(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
        }
        else if(mMap.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID){
            mMap.setMapStyle(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
        }
        else if(mMap.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE){
            mMap.setMapStyle(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí mi .XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_map_layers"
            android:onClick="ChangeType"/>
```

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida. Gracias!

Comment: En java o en Kotlin

Comment: @jorgesys estoy intentándolo hacer en kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás un poco confundido, es muy sencillo cambiar el tipo de mapa en kotlin, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
fun ChangeType(view: View) { //Función que vincula al FloatingRadioButton del XML
    if(mMap.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL){
        mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
    }
    else if(mMap.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID){
        mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
    }
    else if(mMap.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE){
        mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
    }
}
```

¿En que estaba mal?

El método [GoogleMap.setMapStyle()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMapStyle(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions)) se utiliza para cambiarle el **estilo** al mapa, lo que tu quieres hacer es cambiarle el **tipo** al mapa eso se hace con [GoogleMap.setMapType()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#change_the_map_type), son dos conceptos diferentes.

Saludos.